# Remove dots, but keep labels - Chart.js v.2.3.0

Tags: charts, chart.js

How do i remove dots, but keep showing labels on mouse hover from Line chart? 
I've succeeded removing the dots, by setting option, but that also removes the labels:

```
elements: {
            point: {
                     radius: 0
                    }
           }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the documentations here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-element-configuration. Is it possible for you to include a js fiddle of the chart to be used to help find a solution for you.

Comment: I went over the documentation and couldn't find it. I'll try to build a fiddle and update the question, but i think i've put everything needed already.

Comment: I've seen examples in earlier versions where the dots were removed and the labels still showed. so wanted to see what you did that may be causing your issue. Hence asking for the fiddle.